# How to create ipa file without developer account in xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode8

I have installed xcode 8 and developed a project, and now I want to get build file of my project but I do not have a developer account.

What can I do to in order to create a ipa file?

Comment: Do you have provisioning and certificate?

Comment: @iPeter mmm i dont khnow i dont think so i have an free develooper account

Comment: You can easily create an ipa but if you don't create a provisioning profile then you wont  be able to run that ipa in any device.

Comment: @iPeter how can i creat a provisioning profile !?

Comment: @iPeter even i trusted that app in that device my app wont run !?

Comment: provisioning and certificate contains the list of device in which this project will run. If you dont have  provisioning and certificate, i dont think it will be possible to run project in device.

Comment: @dahiya_boy how can creat provisioing list !?

Comment: @MJP https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile.html

Answer (score 1):

You can create ipa below way, but the ipa wont install if you don't create a provisioning or certificate.

1. Find the **.app** file in your project.
2. Ctrl-Click on that file and Show in finder.
3. Drag and drop the file into iTunes.
4. Your app will be shown in iTunes, then again Ctrl-Click on your app and show in finder.

Here you will see your ipa.

> Note: You cannot install this ipa in any device untill you create proper provisioning and certificate.

There are also many ways to create ipa, this is one of those ways.